# Result doesn't show up when emulate with AVD on Mac

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, android-virtual-device

I'm a newbie for Android development. I want to run a Hello World on the emulator in Eclipse as my starting point, but the magic words never show up. I just follow the tutorial, Launch the Android Virtual Device Manager, Create a New AVD and Click Run.
But Everything is fine if it runs on a real device. Is there any special setting on Mac? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait a long time util it appears. I'd advise you to use USB debugging and a real device. It works much faster than the emulator. In addition you can use the app with the normal gestures and all the sensors like camera etc.. But as I said: it's much faster than the AVD.

Answer (score 0):

Check `Console` tab in Eclipse for information about `APK` upload and installation progress.

> Is there any special setting on Mac?

No there is not. Settings are pretty much the same on all platforms.